# firewall-related problems when using YouTube iframe API

Tags: youtube-api

I built an educational web-based game that relies heavily on YouTube-hosted videos played back through the YouTube iframe API which accesses this script file on YouTube's server:

https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api

I am running into two problems when running the game from within a higher-security environment such as is often found within school buildings:

1) In some school systems YouTube is blocked so the game fails at the point when the first movie tries to play.  (Other than moving the movies totally off of YouTube and finding another playback mechanism, I don't know any way to resolve this except to try to convince the administrators to loosen the YouTube restrictions on the network.)

2) Even when the global YouTube block is removed from the firewall, in some cases the game is behaving as if the above script file is totally missing.  My theory is that some of the firewalls are also configured to block cross-site scripting.

Has anyone experienced one or both of these problems, and if so, how were you able to resolve?  In dealing with #2, would it be possible (or even advisable) to pull the JS code from the youtube location and make a local server copy to avoid the presumed cross-site script blocking?

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to host the code for the api locally but that wouldn't solve the problem of the videos being blocked since they too reside on youtube.com.

If loading videos from YouTube is part of the game then you need to communicate that having access to YouTube is a requirement to play it. I don't think there is another option.